# Suggested Edit: Vandalism by Community?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-user

I just rejected the following suggested edit and marked it as vandalism, which to me it seemed to be a clear case of. The weird thing is, the edit was suggested by Community. Does anyone know how/why this edit would have happened? Is this just part of Quality Control, to ensure editors are doing their job properly?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21195466

Comment: It should have shown you that it was indeed an audit, not a real review. You can still see that it was an audit in your link ("Review audit passed...").

Comment: Thanks, normally the "You passed!" response is a lot more noticeable than that, I wasn't expecting such a subdued response :)

Comment: As a side note, "Community" can "suggest" edits- They're actually edits from users that either aren't logged in or don't have an account. So this could happen and not be an audit.

Comment: @Kendra AFAIK, while it's possible to edit anonymously on other SE sites, I believe SO needs all participants to have a registered account first to reduce spam/abuse...

Comment: @AndrewT. Not for edits. If you log out or go incognito, you'll see the "improve" button under posts on main. If you click it, as I just did, you'll get: _"You are not logged in. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed. We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary."_ and the edit box.